# why i don't get full javascript when i try to minified?

Tags: javascript

When i try to minified my javascript file with online tool [online minify tools](https://jscompress.com/) it doesn't get fully minified. Few of the code from the top missing in it. Is there any problem in the code?

Here is my actual code of javascript:

```
var _currentUserFormVersion = 0;
var status;
var myStatus;
var getCompanyDetails = function () {
$("body").mask("");
var id = $("#customer_id").val();
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/web-registation-add-user?id=" + id,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        clearAllInputs();
        $("body").unmask("");
        if (response.registration_details != null) {
            var companyDetails = response.registration_details.company_details;
            $("#companyname").val(companyDetails.company_name);
            $("#firstname").val(companyDetails.first_name);
            $("#lastname").val(companyDetails.last_name);
            $("#mobile").val(companyDetails.mobile_number);
            var salesPerson = companyDetails.registered_by;
            if (!!salesPerson) {
                var salesPersonTxt = $("li[name='" + salesPerson + "']").text();
                $("#referalCode").val(salesPerson);
                $("#salesPersonList").prev().html(salesPersonTxt + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');
            }
            var status_indicator = companyDetails.status;
            // console.log("status: " + status_indicator);
            if (status_indicator == "Active") {
                $("[name='my-checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $("[name='my-checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (companyDetails.customer_type == "Transporter") {
                $("#transporterType").attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                $("#consignorType").attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            if (response.registration_details.customer_details != null) {
                var users = response.registration_details.customer_details;
                for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    $("#addUser").trigger("click");
                    $("#userFirstName" + i).val(users[i].user_first_name);
                    $("#userLastName" + i).val(users[i].user_last_name);
                    $("#userMobileNumber" + i).val(users[i].mobile_no);
                    $("#userMobileNumber" + i).attr('readonly', true);
                    $("#removeUser" + i).remove();
                    $("#password" + i).val(users[i].password);
                    if (users[i].customer_user_status == "Active") {
                        $("#switcher-lg" + i).prop('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        $("#switcher-lg" + i).prop('checked', false);
                    }

                    // set preference form first user
                    if (i == 0) {
                        var goodsType = $("li[name='cargo" + users[i].goods_type_id + "']").text();
                        var bodyType = $("li[name='body" + users[i].body_type_id + "']").text();
                        $("#cargoTypeId").val(users[i].goods_type_id);
                        $("#bodyTypeId").val(users[i].body_type_id);
                        $(".body-type-value").prev().html(users[i].bodyType + "<span class='caret arrow-sales'></span>");

                        $("#goodsTypeList").prev().html(goodsType + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');
                        $("#bodyTypeList").prev().html(bodyType + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');

                        $("#gcity").val(users[i].locations.city_name + ", " + users[i].locations.state_name + ", India");
                        $("#gcityName").val(users[i].locations.city_name);
                        $("#gcityPlaceId").val(users[i].locations.place_id);
                        $("#gcityState").val(users[i].locations.state_name);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (response.registration_details.preferences != null) {
                $("#gcity").val();
            }
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};
initcaption();

$(window).load(function () {
$(".loader").fadeOut("2000");
});

function initializePlugins() {
$.validate({
    form: '#registration, #userDetailsForm'
});
};

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.initCap').on("keyup", function (event) {
    //console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    var c = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var textBox = event.target;
    var start = textBox.selectionStart;
    var end = textBox.selectionEnd;
    textBox.value = textBox.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +       textBox.value.slice(1);
    textBox.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
});
function bindEvents() {
//binding functions
$("#cancelButton").click(function () {
    window.open("/companies", "_self")
});

$("#addUser").click(function () {
    if (_currentUserFormVersion < 5) {
        var formGroupHtml = getFormGroupHtml(_currentUserFormVersion);
        var formSeperator = getFormSeperator(_currentUserFormVersion);
        if (_currentUserFormVersion == 0) {
            $("#userDetailSection").after(formGroupHtml);
        }
        else {
            var lastUser = _currentUserFormVersion - 1;
            $("#userDetailsForm" + lastUser).after(formSeperator + formGroupHtml);
        }

        $("#removeUser" + _currentUserFormVersion).click(function () {
            var formId = $(this).attr("remove-form");
            $("#" + formId).remove();
            $("#" + formId + "Seperator").remove();
            _currentUserFormVersion--;
        });
        $("#userFirstName" + _currentUserFormVersion).keypress(function (e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32);
        });
        $("#userLastName" + _currentUserFormVersion).keypress(function (e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32);
        });
        $("#userMobileNumber" + _currentUserFormVersion).bind("paste", function (e) {
            // access the clipboard using the api
            var _this = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
                var valobj = _this.val();
                valobj = valobj.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
                if (valobj.length >= 10) {
                    var obj = valobj.slice(0, 10);
                    _this.val(obj);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }, 50);
        });
        _currentUserFormVersion++;
        $("[name='user-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
    }

    checkMobileNumber();
    initcaption();

});

$("#save").click(function () {
    if (checkMobileDigits()) {

        state = $("[name='my-checkbox']").prop('checked')
        if (state == true) {
            status = "Active";
        }
        else {
            status = "Inactive";
        }
        $("body").mask("");
        if (validateform()) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var companyInfoJson = getCompanyInfo();
            var userInfoJson = getUserInfo();
            var jsonString = '{' +
                '"registration_details": {' +
                companyInfoJson + ',' +
                userInfoJson +
                '}' +
                '}';
            console.log(jsonString);
            var edit_id = $("#customer_id").val()
            //var SID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 111);
            $.ajax({
                url: serviceURl + "v1/web-registation-add-user?" + "&id=" + edit_id,
                type: "PUT",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: jsonString,
                success: function (data) {
                    clearAllInputs();
                    window.location.replace("/companies");
                    $("body").unmask("");
                    //$("#account-alert").modal("show");
                },
                statusCode: {
                    409: function () {
                        $("body").unmask("");
                        $("#account-exists").modal("show");
                    },
                    500: function () {
                        $("body").unmask("");
                        $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
                    },
                    401: function (error) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(error.responseText)
                        if (!!data && data.error.code == "INVALID_MOBILE") {
                            $("body").unmask("");
                            $("#mobileExist").modal("show");
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("body").unmask("");
                }
            });

        }

    }

});
 };

function getFormGroupHtml(_currentUserFormVersion) {
var formGroupHtml = '<div class="col-md-12 userDetails" id="userDetailsForm' + _currentUserFormVersion + '">' +
    '<div class = "form-group">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-3 pull-right">' +
    '<div class="switchContainer pull-right">' +
    //'<input type="checkbox" id="userCheckbox' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="toggleSwitch" name="user-checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-size="mini" data-on-text="Active" data-off-text="Inactive" checked>' +
    '<div class="form-switcher form-switcher-lg">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" id="switcher-lg' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="toggleSwitch" name="us-checkbox" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-size="mini" data-on-text="Active" data-off-text="Inactive" checked>' +
    '<label class="switcher" for="switcher-lg' + _currentUserFormVersion + '"></label>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-6">' +
    '<div class = "form-group">' +
    '<label for = "userFirstName' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="label-head">First Name <sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk red" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></label>' +
    '<input type = "text" class = "form-control initCap text-box-length input-lg" id = "userFirstName' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" placeholder = "Enter User\'s First Name" data-validation="required" maxlength="20" data-validation-error-msg-container="#userFirstNameErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '">' +
    '<div id="userFirstNameErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-6">' +
    '<div class = "form-group">' +
    '<label for = "userLastName' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="label-head">Last Name</label>' +
    '<input type = "text" maxlength="20" class = "form-control initCap text-box-length input-lg" id = "userLastName' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" placeholder = "Enter User\'s Last Name" data-validation-error-msg-container="#userLastNameErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '">' +
    '<div id="userLastNameErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-6">' +
    '<div class = "form-group">' +
    '<label for = "userMobileNumber' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="label-head">Mobile Number <sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk red" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></label>' +
    '<input autocomplete="off" type = "number" maxlength="10" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" required class = "form-control text-box-length input-lg mobileNo" id = "userMobileNumber' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" placeholder = "Enter User\'s Mobile Number" data-validation="number" onkeydown="restrict()" data-validation-error-msg-container="#userMobileNumberErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '">' +
    '<div id="userMobileNumberErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" ></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="col-md-6">' +
    '<div class = "form-group">' +
    '<label for = "userPassword' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" class="label-head">Password <sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk red" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></label>' +
    '<input autocomplete="new-password" type = "password" class = "form-control text-box-length input-lg" id = "password' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" placeholder = "Enter Password" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg-container="#userPasswordErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '">' +
    '<div id="userPasswordErrorContainer' + _currentUserFormVersion + '"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-12">' +
    '<div style="float: right">';
if (_currentUserFormVersion > 0) {
    formGroupHtml += '<button id="removeUser' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" remove-form="userDetailsForm' + _currentUserFormVersion + '" type="button" class="btn cancel-btn" id="addUser">Remove</button>';
}
formGroupHtml += '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
return formGroupHtml;
 };

function getFormSeperator(_currentUserFormVersion) {
return '<div id="userDetailsForm' + _currentUserFormVersion + 'Seperator" class="col-md-12" style="height: 2px; background-color: #334f7d; margin: 5px 0 20px 0"></div>';
 };

function getUserInfo() {
var bodyTypeId = $("#bodyTypeId").val();
var goodsTypeId = $("#cargoTypeId").val();
var locations = {
    "place_id": $("#gcityPlaceId").val(),
    "state_name": $("#gcityState").val(),
    "city_name": $("#gcityName").val()
};
var userInfoJson = '"customer_details":[';
for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    var status;
    var checkStatus = $("#switcher-lg" + i).prop('checked');
    if (checkStatus) {
        status = "Active"
    } else {
        status = "Inactive"
    }
    var mobile_no = $("#userMobileNumber" + i).val();
    var firstName = $("#userFirstName" + i).val();
    var lastName = $("#userLastName" + i).val();
    var password = $("#password" + i).val();

    var userObject = "";
    if (userInfoJson != '"customer_details":[') {
        userObject += ",";
    }
    userObject += '{' +
        '"mobile_no": ' + mobile_no + ',' +
        '"user_first_name": "' + firstName + '",' +
        '"user_last_name": "' + lastName + '",' +
        '"password": "' + password + '",' +
        '"body_type_id": "' + bodyTypeId + '",' +
        '"goods_type_id": "' + goodsTypeId + '",' +
        '"locations": ' + JSON.stringify(locations) + ',' +
        '"customer_user_status": "' + status + '"' +
        '}';
    userInfoJson += userObject;
}
userInfoJson += ']';
return userInfoJson;
};

function getCompanyInfo() {
var salesGuy = $.trim($('#salesPersonList').prev().text());
var registered_by = (salesGuy == "Salesperson") ? "" : $("#referalCode").val();
var companyInfoJson = '"company_details": {' +
    '"company_name": "' + $("#companyname").val() + '",' +
    '"customer_type": "' + $('input[name=optionsRadiosinline]:checked', '#registration').val() + '",' +
    '"registered_by": "' + registered_by + '",' +
    '"status": "' + status + '"' +
    '}';
return companyInfoJson;
 };


function checkUserDetails() {
if ($("#userFirstName").val() == "" || $("#userMobileNumber").val() == "" || $("#userLastName").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "") {
    $("body").unmask("");
    $("#alerts").modal("show");
    return;
}
for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    if ($("#userMobileNumber" + i).val() == "") {
        $("body").unmask("");
        $("#alerts").modal("show");
        return;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
}

function clearAllInputs() {

for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    $("#userFirstName" + i).val("");
    $("#userMobileNumber" + i).val("");
    $("#userLastName" + i).val("");
    $("#password" + i).val("");
}
$("#companyname").val("");
$("#firstname").val("");
$("#lastname").val("");
$("#mobile").val("");
$("#userFirstName").val("");
$("#userMobileNumber").val("");
$("#userLastName").val("");
$("#password").val("");

}

function checkMobileNumber() {
$('.mobileNo').keypress(function (event) {
    var _this = $(this).val();
    if (_this.length > 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
}

function initcaption() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (this.selectionStart == 0 && event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 && !(event.shiftKey) && !(event.ctrlKey) && !(event.metaKey) && !(event.altKey)) {
            //var $t = $(this);
            event.preventDefault();
            var char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
            $t.val(char + $t.val().slice(this.selectionEnd));
            this.setSelectionRange(1, 1);
        }
    });
});
}

function validateform() {
if ($("#companyname").val() == "" || $("#firstname").val() == "" || $("#mobile").val() == "" || $("#userFirstName").val() == "" || $("#userMobileNumber").val() == "" || $("#userLastName").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" || $("#gcity").val() == "") {
    $("body").unmask("");
    $("#alerts").modal("show");
    return true;
}
for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    if ($("#userFirstName" + i).val() == "" || $("#userMobileNumber" + i).val() == "" || $("#password" + i).val() == "") {
        $("body").unmask("");
        $("#alerts").modal("show");
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

function checkMobileDigits() {
var isValid = false;
for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    if ((!($("#userMobileNumber" + i).val().length == 10))) {
        $("body").unmask("");
        $("#mobile-alert").modal("show");
        isValid = false;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return isValid;
}

restrict = function () {
for (var i = 0; i < _currentUserFormVersion; i++) {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("userMobileNumber" + i);
    textBox.onkeypress = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if (/[^\d]/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    $('#userMobileNumber' + i).on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {
        var reg = /^0+/gi;
        if (this.value.match(reg)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(reg, '');
        }
    });
}
}

getSalesPersonList = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/sales-person",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.sales_person != null) {
            var list = "";
            $.each(response.sales_person, function (index, val) {
                list += "<li name='" + val.referal_code + "'>" + val.first_name + " " + val.last_name + "</li>"
            });
            $("#salesPersonList").append(list);
            $("#salesPersonList li").click(function () {
                var referalCode = $(this).attr('name');
                $("#referalCode").val(referalCode);
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');
            });
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};

getGoodsType = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/cargo-types",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.cargo_types != null) {
            var list = "";
            $.each(response.cargo_types, function (index, val) {
                list += "<li name='cargo" + val.id + "' >" + val.cargo_type_name + "</li>"
            });
            $("#goodsTypeList").append(list);
            $("#goodsTypeList li").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                id = id.replace("cargo", "");
                $("#cargoTypeId").val(id);
                console.log(id);
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").text($(this).text()).html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');

            });
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};

getBodyType = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/body-types",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.body_types != null) {
            var list = "";
            $.each(response.body_types, function (index, val) {
                list += "<li name='body" + val.id + "'>" + val.body_type_name + "</li>"
            });
            $("#bodyTypeList").append(list);
            $("#bodyTypeList li").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                id = id.replace("body", "");
                $("#bodyTypeId").val(id);
                console.log($(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle"));
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');
            });
        }
        getCompanyDetails();
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};


function initialize() {
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
};

var input = document.getElementById('gcity');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log("place_id: " + place.place_id);
    console.log("City: " + place.name);
    console.log("State: " + place.address_components[2].long_name);
    $("#gcityName").val(place.name);
    $("#gcityPlaceId").val(place.place_id);
    $("#gcityState").val(place.address_components[2].long_name);
});
}

getGeoLocation = function () {
// Check if the browser has support for the Geolocation API
if (!navigator.geolocation) {

    findMeButton.addClass("disabled");
    $('.no-browser-support').addClass("visible");

} else {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        console.log(position);
        // Get the coordinates of the current possition.
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(lng);
        codeLatLng(lat, lng)

    });
}
};

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
            //formatted address
            alert(results[0].formatted_address)
            //find country name
            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {

                    //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                    if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                        //this is the object you are looking for
                        city = results[0].address_components[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //city data
            alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
            alert("No results found");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
initializePlugins();
bindEvents();
checkMobileNumber();
getSalesPersonList();
getGoodsType();
getBodyType();
//getGeoLocation();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$("[name='m-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();

$("#userMobileNumber").bind("paste", function (e) {
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
        var valobj = _this.val();
        valobj = valobj.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
        if (valobj.length >= 10) {
            var obj = valobj.slice(0, 10);
            _this.val(obj);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }, 50);
});
});
```

Comment: you should edit your question and put the minified version in - also post what tool/website you used to minify it.

Comment: The minified code will probably just be functionally the same, so if a variable is used just once, it might be replaced by its value in that place without being defined

Comment: There might be some problems in the below code that's why javascript doesn't get minify.

Comment: share your exact problem( as in which of your componenet is not working fine after you minified the js ) along with html and css files. Its difficult to know whether your js is working fine or not by just looking at the minified file.

Comment: @xaxxon I have mentioned a link of online minified script.

Comment: @sandygodhaniya links are inappropriate in quesitnos, because if the link goes away, the question is no longer useful for anyone.

Comment: @AalindSharma I am using minified version of javascript in my site. But some of the code get lost so my site deosn't load and getting the following error in console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: @sandygodhaniya can you add your html and css as well so that i can check your issue ? i cant delve into the minified js if i dont have the html and css.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I have found the solution by other way. Much appreciate for your help..

Answer (score 0):

No, it's normal.

Each minification tool will use an algorithm to replace your long texts to small. This is the reason you feel some of your code got lost. To identify your code from the minified version use the generated **source map**. This will map the minified words to the source. If you have your source maps in the same directory of your js, chrome will fetch it and displays your source instead of the minified source in the source panel.

Answer (score 0):

The minify tool may be trying to optimize your code by removing unnecessary global variables or converting them to local variables, removing function names and directly keeping the function, etc.

Try to execute the minified js once along with html or other supports and see whether it is behaving differently from the original unminified version.

If it is behaving differently then you should try splitting you original unminified code into independent modules and try to minify modules by modules.